# Group by clause limiting items per group

Tags: c#, .net, linq, lambda, linq-to-xml

I have the following XML:

```
<R N="1">
  <MT N="Section" V="Section-1" />
  <MT N="Person" V="John" />
</R>
<R N="2">
  <MT N="Section" V="Section-1" />
  <MT N="Person" V="Peter" />
</R>
<R N="3">
  <MT N="Section" V="Section-2" />
  <MT N="Person" V="Joseph" />
</R>
... ...

<R N="N">
  <MT N="Section" V="Section-J" />
  <MT N="Person" V="PersonX" />
</R>
```

And the following `GroupBy` clause that generates a `IEnumerable<IGrouping<string,XElement>>`:

```
var something = MyElements.GroupBy
(
   x => x.Elements("MT")
   .First
   (
       type => type.Attribute("N").Value == "Section"
   )
   .Attribute("V").Value
   ,
   x=>x
);
```

I would like to have a maximum of 4 items in each group.

I cannot use the `Take` method on the expression `x=>x` since its not an `IEnumerable<T>`.

Do you know how to limit the results for each group?

Comment: Can you describe what data you want to select from xml? Looks like your query is not the best one you can use

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`Take`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb503062%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) like this if all you want is an `IEnumerable<IEnumerable<XElement>>`:

```
var something = MyElements.GroupBy
(
   x => x.Elements("MT")
   .First
   (
       type => type.Attribute("N").Value == "Section"
   )
   .Attribute("V").Value
   ,
   x => x,
   (Key, Items) => Items.Take(4)
);
```

If you need the key as well you can do something like this:

```
var something = MyElements.GroupBy
(
   x => x.Elements("MT")
   .First
   (
       type => type.Attribute("N").Value == "Section"
   )
   .Attribute("V").Value
   ,
   x => x,
   (Key, Items) => new { Key, Items = g.Take(4) }
);
```

Although, you will get an `IEnumerable` of the anonymous type. You would need to iterate over the the `Items` collection. If you can't use an anonymous type (e.g. you need this to be part of a method signature) you could always create your own result type or use a [`Tuple`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.tuple%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Comment: +1 for [GroupBy](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534493(v=vs.110).aspx) overload with result selector (readability is doubtful, but thats single operator call)

Comment: Yes, in my app i need the Key to render the group and all items inside. Anonymous items fits perfect, Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you can use following declarative query to get what you need

```
var xdoc = XDocument.Load(path_to_xml);
var query = from r in xdoc.Descendants("R")
            let section = r.Elements("MT")
                           .First(mt => (string)mt.Attribute("N") == "Section")
                           .Attribute("V")
            group r by (string)section into g
            select g.Take(4);
```